# Laravel Ajax Store Update data issue

Tags: ajax, laravel

i have Form in which i want to update data or store data, right now it is updating data, when i click on update/add button.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <form  id="update-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
@method('PUT')
//text fields

    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg shadow-lg rounded" name="" value="" id="store-data" > <span class="fa fa-user-add "> </span> ADD</button>
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg shadow-lg rounded" name="id" value="{{@$teacher->id}}" id="update-data" > <span class="fa fa-user-edit "> </span> UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

**ajax code for store:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    //Ajax store
    $('#store-data').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers/store",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data: new FormData(this),

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Added");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**ajax code for update:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {

$('#update-form').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(e);

        $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
            url: "teachers/" + $('#update-data').attr("value"),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
      contentType: false,

            beforeSend: function() {

    },
            success: function (data) {
                    alert("updated");
            },

        });
    });
});
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('teachers/store', 'TeachersController@store')->name('add');
Route::resource('teachers', 'TeachersController');
```

**required:**
when i click on add button it should add data, and when i click on update it should update.

Comment: Just put hidden `id` in form and check `if ($id != null) update else store`. you don't need method_put also

Comment: @Fayakon What is your problem? I don't get it from your explanation.

Comment: when i click on add button it should add data, and when i click on update it should update, right now it is updating data in both cases.